# QGIS PyDEV addFeature error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, qgis

Im attempting to run the following code  to test a simple standalone QGIS app and get the the following error.

***Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Eclipse workspace\MyMap\MyMap.py", line 23, in 
    pr.addFeatures([linstr])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addFeatures'***

I have tried several fixes without success.  Fundamentally I don't understand why the error is being generated so it is hard to resolve the issue.   For clarity this comes from the QGIS Python Programming Cookbook 2nd ed.  And line 23 is pr.addFeatures([linstr]).  And i'm running in Eclipse on windows 10

Can anyone help.

```
# Standalone QGIS script
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QgsApplication([], True)
path = "C:/Program Files/QGIS2.18/apps/qgis"
app.setPrefixPath(path, True)
app.initQgis()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
title = "PyQGIS Standalone Application Example"
canvas.setWindowTitle(title)
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
layer_info = 'LineString?crs=epsg:4326'
layer =  QgsVectorLayer(layer_info, 'MyLine' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
linstr = QgsFeature()
wkt = "LINESTRING (1 1, 10 15, 40 35)"
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)
linstr.setGeometry(geom)
pr.addFeatures([linstr])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
canvas.show()
exitcode = app.exec_()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
sys.exit(exitcode)
```

Comment: your path is correct?this errror is because you don't have the correct path to QGIS.If your path is ok try using double \\ : `"C:\\Program Files\\QGIS2.18\\apps\\qgis"`

Comment: Thanks - the path is correct and I tried it with / and \\ options to no effect.